# asdf errors when starting Linux shell

Tags: shell, asdf-vm, direnv

Sorry it's hard to be specific here but I'm struggling to pin down the source of various error messages in my Linux shell with [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com).

I've got Fish shell 3.4.0 running on a RHEL 8.5 GNU/Linux system, and have installed and used `asdf` with it for several months with no problems. I've used `asdf` to install and use Python and R virtual environments with `direnv` as well.

However, starting yesterday, when I open my Gnome Terminal application to start the Fish shell, I get this error:

`environment:987: use_asdf: command not found`

I can still use the shell, but I noticed the the `pipx` tool I installed via my `asdf`-managed Python can no longer be found.

Also, if I start a Bash shell instead, I'm presented with this error:

`bash: register-python-argcomplete: command not found... Install package 'python3-argcomplete' to provide command 'register-python-argcomplete'? [N/y]`

If I choose `N` ("no"), I can still get to the bash shell.

The problem is, I have no idea where these errors are coming from or how to find the root of the problem. How can I begin to troubleshoot these errors?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

`asdf` and its plugins are all fully updated.

There's the output from `asdf info`:

```
OS:
Linux [hostname] 4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:56:54 EST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

SHELL:
fish, version 3.4.1

ASDF VERSION:
v0.10.0-77fd510

ASDF ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:
ASDF_DIR=/home/[username]/.asdf

ASDF INSTALLED PLUGINS:
direnv                       https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-direnv.git master 7dcd571
nodejs                       https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs.git master f9957f3
python                       https://github.com/danhper/asdf-python.git master 57a4d72
R                            https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-r.git master 3eab1a6
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not recognize the `environment:987: use_asdf: command not found` error or the `register-python-argcomplete: command not found` error.

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version of asdf and the latest version of all the asdf plugins you are using. If you still have issues please update you r question with the output from `asdf info` so we can get a better understanding of what your environment is like.

Comment: Thank you @Stratus3D, I have updated the original post with `asdf info`, and yes my `asdf` and plugins are all fully updated.